# Emulator pulseaudio access denied

Tags: android-emulator, pulseaudio

I'm trying to run the android emulator (v 29.3.4.0) on ubuntu 19.10 but I have no sound. When starting from the console, I can see the following errors:

```
$ emulator -avd firstPhone
pulseaudio: Wrong context state
pulseaudio: Reason: Access denied
pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextaudio: Could not init `pa' audio driver
```

I've tried reinstalling pulseaudio and deleting ~/.config/pulse. Nothing helped. I still get the same behavior.

Any ideas where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I ran across your question today looking for a solution myself.  I found something that seems to work.  Not exactly elegant, but it was the best I have found.  Here is what I have:

**System**: Manjaro with qemu **5.1** on the host

The key for me was to modify `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and add (at the bottom):

```
load-module module-native-protocol-unix auth-anonymous=1 socket=/tmp/pulse-socket
```

Then run: `pulseaudio --kill`

(should restart on its own, `pulseaudio --start` if it doesn't)

At this point, `/tmp/pulse-socket` *should* exist.
I did not see this step in the Arch/Manjaro documents I was initially reading.  So this was my sticking point.

Other than that, it it comes down to the steps in the Arch wiki:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Passing_VM_audio_to_host_via_PulseAudio

Specifically, my `virsh edit <vm-name>` looks like this at the bottom *(don't forget changes to the `domain` line at the top too):*

```
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-object'/>
    <qemu:arg value='input-linux,id=mouse1,evdev=/dev/input/by-id/usb-1bcf_USB_Optical_Mouse-event-mouse'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-object'/>
    <qemu:arg value='input-linux,id=kbd1,evdev=/dev/input/by-id/usb-0c45_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd,grab_all=on,repeat=on'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
    <qemu:arg value='ich9-intel-hda,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1b'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
    <qemu:arg value='hda-micro,audiodev=hda'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-audiodev'/>
    <qemu:arg value='pa,id=hda,server=unix:/tmp/pulse-socket,out.buffer-length=512,timer-period=1000'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
```

The evdev lines are unrelated to sound, but I put them in for context (assuming you are using evdev to share keyboard and mouse).

Note I did NOT have to make any changes to `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` to get sound to work (though I did for evdev with the keyboard/mouse).  I also did NOT have to setup the `/root/.config/pulse` directory since I am using an anonymous socket.

Comment: Yes, I believe anonymous solves some of the issues.